# Quality not proper while rendering it via threejs r71

Tags: three.js, textures

I am rendering a sofa using r71 but the texture quality is not proper. If I render it through r58 then it looks really good. It is a bug or what?? Below are the images, first one is rendered via r58 and second one via r71.

[image: rendered via r58]

[image: rendered via r71]

Comment: Have you try to change minFilter and magFilter?

Comment: I am loading models via JSONLoader(). How to apply filters directly to the texture as we consume materials in JSONLoader? If I was using THREE.loadTexture then I would have easily applied it

Comment: can't it be about shading ? You can try `material.shading = THREE.FlatShading` as the actual default one is `THREE.SmoothShading` that spreads shadows and can be the cause of this darker look. I dont know which was the default one in r58. Also its not resoluted enough but it seems there is less details on the second picture, as BenMack said it could be about filters : try `material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter`. Same if you have a bumpmap/normal texture : `material.bumpMap...`
Change material parameters in the loader callback, before you create the mesh.

Comment: But why do I need to do all this?? The model is same why there is a quality difference in both the versions? Is it a bug or new version of threejs recommends doing all this?

Comment: @Tarun you can ping someone with @+name. As Falk Thiele answered things changed from a revision to an other, just play with the parameters we wrote you and it probably will get fixed

Comment: Ya I played with the parameters and I got close but can't match the quality which came via r58.

Comment: are you using subdivision by any chance?

Comment: really hard to see what is actually going on here, i'd put the same camera angle for both shots, and zoom in to the middle area with the seam and artifacts

Answer (score 0):

Coming from r58 a lot of things has changed, for you especially how they calculate gamma and hardwireing the ambient term to the diffuse color. 
The main difference I see is your model appears darker.

To make the model appear brighter you could set the materials color to white: `material.color.setHex( 0xFFFFFF );`.

If this is still not bright enough I discovered a little Hack by setting the HSL Lighting value to something > 1. `material.color.setHSL( 0, 0, 6 );`

Without providing the code on how you create your material its only a shot in the dark.

Comment: Its not about the brightness. Even If I put some light on it then also texture quality is not that crisp.